# Converting objects in my MVC3 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

A user can upload a new document and add information, every document has a set of default properties. The admin has the ability to add a small amount of extra properties. He can add a string, bool, datetime value.

When generating my View I get a `Dictionary<String,Object>` with the extra properties.
In my view I want to generate the right control for the object. So when it's a datetime object I want to load the jquery calendar, boolean a checkbox etc.

```
@switch (Model.ExtraFields[i].PropertyType)
    {
        case (short)Enums.PropertyType.Boolean:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Convert.ToBoolean(Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue))
   break;
        case (short)Enums.PropertyType.DateTime:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue))
   break;
        default:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue)
        break;
    }
```

It always gives an error on the Convert.To...

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditorFor`, `TextBoxFor` and so on all require an expression which gives them access to meta data on the property that you're using. `Convert.ToDateTime` removes that access (because it returns a value instead) so the methods don't know what property name to use or any additional information like a `[Display]` attribute. I would suggest you do something like:

```
@switch (Model.ExtraFields[i].PropertyType) {
    case (short)Enums.PropertyType.Boolean:
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue, "BooleanEditor")
        break;
    case (short)Enums.PropertyType.DateTime:
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue, "DateTimeEditor")
        break;
    default:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Values[i].ExtraFieldValue)
        break;
}
```

Then you create `EditorTemplates` (as a subdirectory of your controller with specific templates named `BooleanEditor.cshtml` and so forth like so:

```
@model object
@Html.CheckBox("", Convert.ToBoolean(Model))
```

by leaving the first parameter blank you're going to automatically use the property name supplied via the expression from the call to `EditorFor`.

Comment: Ok , the error is gone and I can submit the boolean value. But when changing the check box he submits both values and I get a String[] as object with [0] as last selected value and [1] as first value :s

Comment: That's because the `Html.CheckBox` and `Html.CheckBoxFor` emit both a checkbox and a **hidden** input element. The hidden value will be the value that was initially by the model. This is so that you can see what has changed. I haven't looked into this too deeply but the hidden value should be your second element. (You've given me something to research)

Comment: I have noticed that it will always just returns a 'String[]', So I just convert my object to it and just get the first value

Comment: Yes, because all values are inherently strings when dealing with post values. Gonna find a model binder example real quick.